# Surface Pen issues when dragging and dropping in Chrome and Edge

Tags: google-chrome, drag-and-drop, microsoft-edge, pixelsense

I'm testing a client's Surface 4 device. As the title suggests, in-page dragging and dropping isn't working when using touch (finger dragging) or the Surface Pen. After some testing it seems this is an issue in both Chrome and Edge, but not in Firefox.

Drag and drop functionality works as expected on the desktop, but not in-browser. I've also checked Chrome's Event Listener and, as it turns out, dragging (both using the pen and touch) does not trigger any drag or drop events.

I've read about Chrome freezing when using a Surface Pen but can't find any other cases of drag-and-drop issues. I'm not sure if this is related at all but that should have been fixed in the Chrome 60 update. The client pointed out that they installed a Windows Security Update just before they noticed the issue. Any reason this could be related? Any similar experiences or fixes?

Answer (score 3):

This issue relates to Chrome's configuration, not Windows 10 or the pen settings. Chrome's default behavior is to interpret pen click-dragging as scrolling. You can disable this behavior:

1. Navigate to `chrome://flags` in the Chrome address bar
2. Find *Direct Manipulation Stylus Windows*
3. Change dropdown on right to *Disabled*
4. Restart Chrome

This will allow you to click and drag web elements with a stylus and maintain scrolling behavior for (finger) touch input.

Comment: In 2021 Brave that setting is called "Touch initiated drag and drop" and it needs to be *enabled*, but once it is, drag and drop works with finger or stylus.